# What is the smoothing method used in type "contour" with plotly in R?

Tags: r, plotly, contour, smoothing, r-plotly

I am making a contour plot in R using plotly. I want to know what smoothing method is used (is it loess or something different?)

All the documentation I could find was that:

- You can set smoothing as a number between or equal to 0 and 1.3 (default = 1)
- Description: It sets the amount of smoothing for the contour lines, where "0" corresponds to no smoothing.

My code:

`m <- matrix(data = rnorm(56), ncol = 8, nrow = 7)
plot_ly(z = m, type = "contour")`

My results:
[Contour plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7xUu.png)

Thank you!
Joan